# How to get in-sample forecast for ARIMA model in R?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, arima

I am using the code below:

```
#Training seasonal ARIMAx model on input dataset
fit<-arima(visits_ts, order=c(1,0,0),seasonal=c(1,0,0),xreg=reg,method="CSS")

#Forecasting for future
pred<-predict(fit,n.ahead=13, newxreg=nreg)
```

The code only generates out of sample forecast. However, I would also like to see the in-sample forecast for the training data set. How can I get the in-sample forecast?

Comment: What you are asking for are fitted values. They can be obtained this way: `fitted <- visits_ts-resid(fit)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The statistical part of the question is understanding that the in-sample one-step-ahead forecasts of an ARIMA model are actually the fitted values of that model.

In R, the method `fitted` applied on model output object normally returns the fitted values of the model. However, the method is not applicable to the output of function `arima`. There is a workaround: fitted values equal original values minus residuals. Residuals can be extracted from a fitted object using the method `residuals` (and that applies to the output of function `arima`). In your case,

```
fitted <- visits_ts - residuals(fit)
```

Comment: Better still, use the `forecast` package which does have a `fitted` method for outputs from `Arima` and `auto.arima`.