# Fit and Predict Arima in R

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I am trying to fit a Arima model in R with an independent variable (ARIMAX). 
The model fit data contains both positive and negative numbers. The issue is that after fitting the model, the predict function throws out numbers which are not even close to data that was used to fit the model.

```
# Sample Data
y <- c( -0.05628948,  0.01907727,  0.00000000, -0.01907727,  0.00000000, -0.01940678,
0.05724351, -0.01875946, -0.03848405,  0.05724351)
x <- c(0.000000000,-0.071700531 ,-0.023863364,  0.013701646,  0.000000000,  0.085009788,
  -0.028666940, -0.046181130, -0.027316528,  0.006895152)

#Fit the model
model <- arima(y, order=c(2,0,1),fixed = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),xreg=x)

#Use the predict function with x again as the input
fore <- predict(model,newxreg = x)[1]

########################Output########################################
Model - 
Call:
arima(y, order = c(2, 0, 1), xreg = x, fixed = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1  intercept       x
      -0.7935  -0.5747  -0.2986    -0.0010  0.0569
s.e.   0.4327   0.4399   0.6892     0.0026  0.1245

sigma^2 estimated as 0.0005055:  log likelihood = 22.91,  aic = -33.83

Predict - 

> fore
$`pred`
Time Series:
Start = 11 
End = 20 
Frequency = 1 
[1] -0.03206240 -0.03614031 -0.03341961 -0.03128313 -0.03206240 -0.02722754
[7] -0.03369281 -0.03468892 -0.03361601 -0.03167025
```

Not sure why all the values from predict are only negative (while the original y has both positive and negative) and so off from the original y values. Please advise. Thanks!

[image: x and y]

Answer (score 2):

Calling `predict()` generates *forecasts*, not *in-sample fits*. In your particular case, the forecasts are associated with the exact same predictor values `x` as were used in model fitting, but `predict()` of course does not care about this. And of course, forecasts usually do not look similar to the historical data (or to in-sample fits).

[To get in-sample fits, subtract the residuals:](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/198664/1352)

```
plot(y,type="o")
lines(y-residuals(model),col="red")
```

[image: arima]

[Better still, use the `forecast` package, which does have a `fitted` method for outputs from `Arima()` and `auto.arima()`.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198662/how-to-get-in-sample-forecast-for-arima-model-in-r#comment376593_198664)